# How do I enable opcache with PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, php-5.3, opcode-cache

For various reasons, I can't upgrade PHP to 5.5. I have PHP 5.3, is there a way to do opcode caching with 5.3?

Comment: You install it in the same way you install any other extension. There should be more info at https://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php):

> This extension is bundled with PHP 5.5.0 and later, and is » available
>   in PECL for PHP versions 5.2, 5.3 and 5.4.